# background image TextField doesn´t appear

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uitextfield, textfield

I have XCode 4.2

In interface builder i´m choosing a background image for my TextField but it just doesn´t appear. I did the same for a custom button and worked great. Don´t know what i´missing.

Dumb question, but i can´t figured it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possibly one of the following...
If the textfield is disabled or if the borderStyle value is set to the UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect style, the custom background image associated with the text field is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

The custom background image associated with the text field would be visible.

```
 self.textfieldName.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
textfield.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleNone;

textfield.background=[UIImage imageNamed:@"txt2.jpg"];
```